# Creating groups based on UTC Time

Tags: r, mean, utc, posixct

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
str(m12)'data.frame':   48178 obs. of  10 variables:
$ created_utc  : POSIXct, format: "2016-04-19 02:59:02" "2016-05-01 01:51:58" "2016-04-20 15:11:24" "2016-04-26 23:09:13" ...
$ WC           : int  122 24 27 34 43 30 18 49 52 16 ...
$ Analytic     : num  74.05 6.55 1.32 26.21 11.64 ...
$ Clout        : num  20.6 1 35.5 38.4 40.8 ...
$ Authentic    : num  80.8 91.3 92.5 14.7 87.5 ...
....
```

I want to calculate the average score for every variable for every single day.

I tried this:

```
mean <- aggregate(m12[, 2:10], list(m12$created_utc), mean)
```

It calculates the mean for every second, but I need it for every day. Do you know of a way to achieve that?

*sorry for not providing sample data. I simply do not know how to create a POSIXct variable.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert the 'created_utc' to `Date` class so the time part will be stripped off.  Then, use it as the grouping variable, to get the `mean` of each column for a single day.

```
aggregate(.~cbind( created_utc= as.Date(created_utc)), m12, FUN = mean, 
          na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

---

Faster approaches are using `dplyr` or `data.table`

```
library(dplyr) 
m12 %>%
    group_by(created_utc = as.Date(created_utc)) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean= mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Or

```
setDT(m12)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE) , .(created_utc = as.Date(created_utc))]
```

Comment: It works smoothly. I used the version with dplyr. Thank you!